# How cancel pending queries when one fails in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

i have a GraphQL server running with NestJs. When i make a request with various queries, i want cancel every pending observables and return the error when one of those fails. I use Axios for http client.

So, when one fail return the error of that observable and the server response, so the request is ended. But every other observables still alive and get complete over time, and never reach the client because the request is ended.

How i cancel all pending observables??

```
query combine {
  firstQuery { <--- this fail
    fieldOne
  }
  secondQuery { <-- this keep the request alive
    secondOne
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
In the example, both queries make an Http Request to another resource with Axios Http Client. So, when one of them throw an error, the server GraphQL return the error, but the another request is still alive, is not being cancel or unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server-side problem. GraphQL supports partial responses, as you're experiencing first-hand now. If an error is thrown while resolving a field, the field will resolve to null and the error will be added to the `errors` array inside the response.

However, if the field where the error occurs is non-null, the error will "bubble up" the parent field. If that field is also non-null, it will bubble up to its parent, and so on until it hits a nullable field or the root.

What this means is that a schema like this:

```
type Query {
  firstQuery: SomeType
  secondQuery: SomeOtherType
}
```

will allow either either (`firstQuery` or `secondQuery`) to throw during execution without affecting the other. But we can do this:

```
type Query {
  firstQuery: SomeType!
  secondQuery: SomeOtherType!
}
```

and we'll simply get `null` for the `data` in the response if either field throws.

Comment: Hi, i update the question explain better the case. 

(n the example, both queries make an Http Request to another resource with Axios Http Client. So, when one of them throw an error, the server GraphQL return the error, but the another request is still alive, is not being cancel or unsubscribe)